# Multiple searching in Asp.net (entity framework) with multiple search boxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jv25.png)I'm having a problem to develop a form that can be search by multiple search boxes.....when i'm trying to search name and email together ActionResult...compiler says both linq queries cannot be applied with && operator..i don.t know why...

---

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string search,string search2)
{
     var obj = db.Emps.Where(x => x.Employee_name.StartsWith(search)) && db.Emps.Where(x=>x.Employee_email.StartsWith(search2));
     return View(obj);
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your current code, the first part `db.Emps.Where(x => x.Employee_name.StartsWith(search))` is going to return a collection, `IQueryable<Emp>`
and the second part of the expression will also return the same type, `IQueryable<Emp>`.

So your code is basically trying to execute/compile the expression `IQueryable<Emp> && IQueryable<Emp>` and since it is not valid, the compiler is telling you that it is not valid.

Ideally, you should have both of your WHERE condition predicates inside the same `Where` method.

```
var obj = db.Emps.Where(x => x.Employee_name.StartsWith(search) 
                          && x.Employee_email.StartsWith(search2));
```

Keep in mind that, the variable `obj` is still of type `IQueryable<Emp>`. If you want to execute your LINQ query, you may call the `ToList()` method.

```
List<Emp> = db.Emps.Where(x => x.Employee_name.StartsWith(search) 
                            && x.Employee_email.StartsWith(search2)).ToList();
```

If you make the above change, make sure your view is strongly typed to `List<Emp>` instead of `IQueryable`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both conditions inside single `Where`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string search,string search2)
{
     var obj = db.Emps.Where(x => x.Employee_name.StartsWith(search) && x.Employee_email.StartsWith(search2));
     return View(obj);
}
```